# Show a dialog with a text input field and an image in AppleScript

Tags: bash, dialog, applescript

I am very new to AppleScript. I am writing a `bash` script and I need the user type a CAPTCHA. I am trying to use AppleScript to show  a dialog with the CAPTCHA image (a simple `.png` image) and a text input box to the user and then get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppleScript’s native dialog display facilities (aka [display dialog](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW12) and [display alert](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW11)) are rather limited and won’t allow you to display an image, unless you define it as an OS X icon file (`.icns`) of the right size, which might not be very practical for a captcha.

However, there is at least one alternative I am aware of: [Carsten Blüm’s *Pashua*](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/pashua/) will allow you to create native Cocoa dialogs containing both `textfield` and `image` elements. As these are defined in a DSL and created by Pashua, they can be used straight from a shell script (no need to interpose AppleScript – check out the documentation and example shell script distributed with Pashua).